# Recommended practices regarding transfering database from Joomla 1.5 to Joomla 3

Tags: joomla-3.x, database, sql, joomla-1.5

I want to transfer about 300 articles from a Joomla 1.5 website to a Joomla 3.3.1 website.

I have access only to the Joomla 1.5 database but not to the backend (I have access to both for the joomla 3.3.1 website).

Because the table xx_content under Joomla 3.3 doesn't have the same structure/columns than the table xx_content under Joomla 1.5, I can't simply do a SQL query (both tables are in the same database).

So what is the recommended practices to do that?

My guess is: export the J1.5 xx_content to a csv and then modify it to reflect the structure of the J3.3 xx_content and then import it in J3.3 xx_content. But I wonder if there isn't something easier.

Comment: Just a note: If you have database access, it's not that hard to set up a new backend user or reset the password of an existing backend user.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

What I would recommend you do is:

1. Export the database for the Joomla 1.5 site, apart from the `#__users` table
2. Install a fresh copy of Joomla 1.5 on your localhost
3. Import the database dump you downloaded before

**You should now have a fresh Joomla 1.5 site with all you content.**

1. Install [redMIGRATOR](http://redcomponent.com/redcomponent/redmigrator) which is a Joomla 1.5 extension that will migrate your site to Joomla 3.x
2. Once your site has been successfully migrated, take a database dump of the `#__content` table.
3. On your **live** Joomla 3 site that you said you have access to, import the database dump that you took from your localhost.

Hope this helps

Comment: That's a great idea! Thanks Lodder! I going to do that right now.

Comment: No worries, let me know how it all goes

Comment: I was about to start when I realized I had to edit all the fulltext entries so I did it via CSV, but if I didn't have to do it, I would I go with your solution! That would have been a safer and quicker way of doing it!

Answer (score 4):

Finally, I've done the export/import via CSV (as I also had to edit all the fulltext entries) and here are the little things that I had to search for:

1. export the Db via CSV, then edit it with Open Office Calc*
2. edit the column so that they match the Joomla3.3 structure.
3. set the column `asset_idFK` to `O`, Joomla will assign the correct value when you will open/save your article from the backend/frontend.

**To encapsulate all the entries with** `"`

1. Still in Open Office Calc, format all the cells to text :  CTRL+A, right click , check text
2. Select Save As: CSV and check "edit filter settings"
3. In the pop up, "keep same format" (don't choose ODT) and check:  quote all text cells (cf. this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10905588/exporting-csv-properly-open-office-save-numbers-as-text) for screen shoot)

**Escaped comma**:
I don't know why but Open Office replaces all the escaped comma `\"` by `\""`, so open the .csv with a text editor as Notepad++ and Find replace `\""`  by  `\"`

- I have tried to do it with Excel, but because I have special western characters, I ended up with a corrupted characters. But if you have to do it with Excel, add `sep=;` at the first line of the .CSV to tell Excel what are the separator.